# GCP Secret Manager throws: "path" argument must be of type string

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm working on using the [GCP Secrets Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-nodejs) from Node.js 8.x (I know, it's ancient, but it's the newest GA Node runtime on Cloud Functions). However, when I run their example, it keeps throwing gRPC error from [this line](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-secret-manager/blob/v3.0.0/src/v1/secret_manager_service_client.ts#L156):

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
```

Line of code I'm trying to test:

```
const secretClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
```

I get the same error if I'm running on Node 8.x or Node 10.x, and if I use the latest version of the secrets lib (`3.0.0`) or the legacy version for Node 8.x (`1.2.1`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this error occurred because the library is running *browser* rather than *Node* mode, which forces it to avoid "fallback" mode, trying to lookup the gRPC path incorrectly. The decision is because `window` is in scope, tricking the [`isBrowser` logic](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-secret-manager/blob/v3.0.0/src/v1/secret_manager_service_client.ts#L110).

**Root Cause**

The root cause is that `jest` was used to test, which by [default runs in `jsDom` mode](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string), inserting globals like `window`.

**Fix**

Add the following to your `jest.config.json` file.

```
testEnvironment: 'node',
```